# Tips on guides on Android for an iOs developer?

Tags: java, android, objective-c

Are there any good guides around which can help me starting with Android development? At the moment I'm full-time on iOs and we are looking for a way to start making (simple) Android apps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html), there are lots of topics covered and it's regularly updated with the newest info about the API's. It will be a good start for you to cover this guide. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, found that one already, but it would be nice to have some iOs related stuff :)

Comment: @ejazz, iOS related? What do you mean?

Comment: I can program in Objective-c and iOs. And I'm wondering if there are any tutorials which compare iOs elements (like uitableview) with android elements